# Passing Value of Toast from a Service and display it in a TextView

Tags: android, service

I would like to know, how I can pass or get the value from a `Toast`, so that I can display the value in my `TextView`.

**edit**

this part of mycode in service

```
public void onStart(Intent i, int stID){
   super.onStart(i, stID);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Horas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

the following code it's the part of my mainactivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   //this code to call the service
   startService(new Intent (this, MyService.class));
}
```

so what i can add in my service or in my mainactivity, that allow me to get and show the message in textview
Can someone help me solve this issue?

Comment: use a handler. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Comment: i can't usderstand about your link, can you give spesific way, so i can easy to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
static String toast_msg;
  public void onStart(Intent i, int stID){
  toast_msg="Horas"; 
   super.onStart(i, stID);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast_msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Add this line of code also

```
TextView Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.input);
Text.setText(MyService.toast_msg)
```

Comment: i already add it, but it still not give and show the result in textview, can you help me to solve it?

Comment: Is your text view(where you want to display data) in a new java class  ?

Comment: Try change **String toast_msg** to **static String toast_msg.** and try

Comment: and also add **toast_msg="Horas"** before  **super.onStart(i, stID);**.. you can discard the previous comment

Comment: i want display the data in MainActivity class, i have try to change String toast_msg to static String toast_msg, and if i follow your code it's make error, so do like this  Text.setText(MyService.toast_msg); but it's still do not give the result.

Comment: Can you upvote ? i have edited my answer.. and you can mark that as correct if that worked

Comment: how i mark the correct, i never do before, can you tell me how to mark it? it's work when i add toast_msg="horas" before super.onStar(i, stID);

Answer (score 1):

Store the toast message in string varible and access this variable from the activity

```
  String toast_msg;
  public void onStart(Intent i, int stID){
  super.onStart(i, stID);
  toast_msg="Horas";
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast_msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

in activity make an object of service class and access the toast_msg

Comment: how i make a object and access it in activity, can you show me ?

Comment: In your Activity make an object like this
 
Myservice obj= new Myservice();//Myservice is the name of service class

now 

tv.setText(obj.toast_msg);//textview is an object of TextView

Comment: i already do that your answer, but it still do not show the result in textview,

Comment: i already do, and add like this MyService obj = new MyService(); tv = (TextView) fingViewByid(R.id.lblMessage); tv.setText(obj.toast_msg); it's still donot give the result into screen, can anybody help me?